# Apache запретить доступ к файлам, Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, apache

Всем привет. По пути `storage/5/sas24s15.png` лежит картинка. Эта картинка принадлежит конкретному пользователю, только он может получить к ней доступ. Мой возможный вариант реализации: в таблице БД хранить путь к файла, символическую ссылку и оригинально название.

Пользователь переходит по пути `storage/5/ajs5`, проверяются права и перенаправляет на нужную ссылку. Имя файла - рандомный набор символов длиной от 30 до 250 символов. Но, вижу недочёт, вдруг кто-то поделится абсолютной ссылкой, то другой сможет скачать этот файл без проблем. Да, конечно можно после получения одной ссылки сразу же менять запись в БД.

Как настроить Apache под Laravel ?(перенаправлять на нужный контроллер, который решает отдать файл или нет). Или же использовать мой вариант?

Answer (score 1):

Вкратце так:

Маршрут -

```
Route::get('files/{filename}', 'HomeController@getFile');
```

Контроллер -

```
class HomeController extends Controller
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }
    public function getFile($filename)
    {
        // проверяем может ли \Auth::user() скачивать файл $filename;
       if( ... ) {
           return response()->download(storage_path('files/'.$filename), null, [], null); 
       } else {
           abort(403);
       }
    }
}
```

Файлы мы храним соответственно в `/storage/files` куда публичного доступа нет.

Answer (score 0):

**1)** Картинки загружать не в `public` директорию.

**2)** Сделать контроллер - который, например, при урле: `http://example.com/image/123` берет `123` (тобишь наш `id` для поиска по базе) и ищет картину.

**3)** Если картинка найдена - смотрим кто её запрашивает (по кукам, сессиям или как вы там идентифицируете пользователя) если тот у кого есть права на просмотр, то отображаем картинку, например так:

```
$file = "<Путь к картинке>";
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
readfile($file);
exit();
```

И будет вывод как настоящей картинки. Таким способом вы сохраняете путь к картинке закрытым и перед тем как показать изображение обрабатываете `php` скриптом